# coffeescript require module hangs

Tags: express, coffeescript

Folks,
  The following hangs when calling `http://localhost:3000/file/sync`

app.coffee:

```
express = require('express')
jsonFun = require('./jsonFun')
app = express()

exports.app = app

app.configure () ->
    app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
    app.use express.bodyParser()
    app.use express.logger('dev')
    app.use app.router


app.get '/hello/:name', (req, res) ->
    res.send 'hello ' + req.params.name

app.get '/file/sync', (req, res) ->
    jsonFun.syncJSON



app.listen 3000
console.log "Listening on 3000..."
```

jsonFun.coffee:

```
fs = require 'fs'

module.exports.syncJSON = ->
    console.log 'syncJSON Called'
    res.send 'json file results ' + req

module.exports.asyncJSON = ->
    console.log 'asyncJSON Called'
```

What would be the proper syntax to include the jsonFun.coffee file, and pass along the req, res and have it return responses?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To call a function in CoffeeScript, ones needs either arguments or parens :

```
# this is a call
ok(1)
# this is a call, too
ok 1
# this is a parameter-less call
ok()
# this is just a variable access
ok
```

Just use `.syncJSON()`

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
app.get '/hello/:name', (req, res) ->
    res.send 'hello ' + req.params.name
```

.

```
module.exports.syncJSON = (req, res)->
    console.log 'syncJSON Called'
    res.send 'json file results '
```